# Overriding keypress

Tags: c#

I know this may be an easy answer to some of you but i dont know how to properly do this. Ive created a text editor, that also has a docking window that will display functions. I have it set up in the menu that F8 is the shortcut key for showing the function window. I would also like to catch the F8 keypress event to parse the current data for the functions in the program but I cant get this to happen..

Comment: whats weird is i can press any of the f keys and nothing happens but if i press a regular key then it stops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture your Text Editors KeyPressed Event and check the `KeyEventArgs` that are coming in, then mark the not handled as false which will cause the event to be passed up to the parent control:

Example

```
KeyPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F8) DoSomething();
    e.Handled = false;
}
```

In response to the comment that you added to your question. You may need to set the controls KeyPreview to True. I think that KeyPreview may be available at only the form level, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I think you have it backwards. Setting the 'e.Handled' property to true will prevent the event propagating up the control tree while setting 'e.Handled' to false will allow the other controls to capture it.

Comment: Oh, wait. Sorry, I thought you were saying the opposite. Confusing. May want to re-word your answer a little.

Answer (score 1):

Set up an event handler for the `OnKeyPress` (or `OnKeyDown` or `OnKeyUp`) event, and check which key was pressed (it will be in the event arguments). Then, you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the tagged answer is correct.  The KeyPress event handler won't handle the Function keys; you need to use KeyUp event handler or ProcessDialogKey method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand everything, but can't you use the [KeyPress Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) available in any Control ?